# Imprimir valores diferentes si se actualiza la pantalla con JavaScript

Tags: javascript

un saludo para todos espero se encuentren muy bien.

Estoy usando la librería highcharts para sacar una gráfica de calor, esta gráfica me actualiza en tiempo real los valores.

Lo que estoy buscando es que automáticamente al actualizar la pantalla me imprima valores distintos o aleatorios.

Este es mi código:

Librería y HTML:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/heatmap.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px; max-width: 800px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
  var dataForSeries = [
      [0, 0, 10],
      [0, 1, 19],
      [0, 2, 8],
      [0, 3, 24],
      [0, 4, 67],
      [1, 0, 92],
      [1, 1, 58],
      [1, 2, 78],
      [1, 3, 117],
      [1, 4, 48],
      [2, 0, 35],
      [2, 1, 15],
      [2, 2, 123],
      [2, 3, 64],
      [2, 4, 52],
      [3, 0, 72],
      [3, 1, 132],
      [3, 2, 114],
      [3, 3, 19],
      [3, 4, 16],
      [4, 0, 38],
      [4, 1, 5],
      [4, 2, 8],
      [4, 3, 117],
      [4, 4, 115],
      [5, 0, 88],
      [5, 1, 32],
      [5, 2, 12],
      [5, 3, 6],
      [5, 4, 120],
      [6, 0, 13],
      [6, 1, 44],
      [6, 2, 88],
      [6, 3, 98],
      [6, 4, 96],
      [7, 0, 31],
      [7, 1, 1],
      [7, 2, 82],
      [7, 3, 32],
      [7, 4, 30],
      [8, 0, 85],
      [8, 1, 97],
      [8, 2, 123],
      [8, 3, 64],
      [8, 4, 84],
      [9, 0, 47],
      [9, 1, 114],
      [9, 2, 31],
      [9, 3, 48],
      [9, 4, 91]
    ],
    dataForSeriesLength = dataForSeries.length;

  Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
      type: 'heatmap',
      marginTop: 40,
      marginBottom: 80,
      plotBorderWidth: 1,
      events: {
        load: function() {
          var chart = this,
            series = chart.series[0],
            changingDataInterval = setInterval(function() {
              for (var i = 0; i < dataForSeriesLength; i++) {
                dataForSeries[i][2] = parseInt(Math.random() * 100);
              }

              series.update({
                data: dataForSeries
              });
            }, 1000);
        }
      }
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Análisis de Calor Tasa Estimada de Apertura'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['6 am - 8 am', '8 am - 10 am', '10 am - 12 pm', '12 pm - 2 pm', '2 pm - 4 pm', '4 pm - 6 pm', '6 pm - 8 pm', '8 pm - 10 pm', '10 pm - 12 am', '12 am - 2 am', '2 am - 4 am', '4 am - 6 am'],
        title: {
            text: 'Horas'
        }
    
    },
    yAxis: {
      categories: ['Viernes', 'Jueves', 'Miércoles', 'Martes', 'Lunes'],
      title: null
    },
    colorAxis: {
      min: 0,
      minColor: '#FFFFFF',
      maxColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3]
    },
    legend: {
        align: 'right',
        layout: 'vertical',
        margin: 0,
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 25,
            enabled: false,
        symbolHeight: 280
    },
    tooltip: {
      formatter: function() {
        return '<b>' + this.series.xAxis.categories[this.point.x];
      }
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'Datos',
      borderWidth: 0,
      data: dataForSeries,
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false,
        color: '#000000'
      }
    }]
  });
});
```

Comment: Estas buscando que el array `dataForSeries` se cargue aleatoriamente?

Comment: Si, cada vez que actualice la pantalla, actualmente lo que hace es cambiar los datos aleatoriamente con: dataForSeries[i][2] = parseInt(Math.random() * 100);

Comment: Hola @NicolasCavilla un saludo, efectivamente eso es lo que estoy buscando hacer.